# Unexpected token when trying to subscribe

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to understand `Meteor.publish()` and `Meteor.subscribe()`, with help from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIKYpjmWThU).

I have a collection defined like this:

```
export const Chansons = new Mongo.Collection('chansons');
```

Which I publish on my server:

```
Meteor.publish("chansons", function(){
  return Chansons.find();
});
```

But then when I try to subscribe to it on my client, I have an error:

> While building for web.browser:
>
> ```
>   imports/ui/body.js:17:14: Unexpected token, expected ";" (17:14)
> ```

What I do not get is that I wrote the code exactly like in the video, and it worked at first!

```
constructor() {
  super();
  
  this.state = {
    subscription: {
      chansons: Meteor.subscribe("chansons")
    }
  }
}
```

I then changed the formatting of my code somewhere else and now this error appeared and I cannot seem to fix it.

The error seems to come from the `constructor()`, since it goes away when I delete this block of code.

I know this question is really stupid, but I have no idea how to fix this.

edit: here is the whole `body.js`:

```js
//Importation des méthodes
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Chansons } from '../api/chansons.js'

//Importation de body
import './body.html';
//Importation des templates
import './templates/header.html';
import './templates/youTube.html';
import './templates/search.html';
import './templates/parametres.html';
import './templates/affichagePlaylist.html';


//Subscription à la collection de chansons
constructor() {
  super();

  this.state = {
    subscription: {
      chansons: Meteor.subscribe("chansons")
    }
  }
}

//Lancement de YouTube

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player("player", {
      //height: "400",
      //width: "600",
      videoId: "fkk1vg0nAfc",
      events: {
        onReady: function (event) {
          event.target.playVideo();
        }
      }
    });
  };
  YT.load();
};

Template.body.helpers({
  chansons(){
    return Chansons.find({})
  }
});

Template.search.events({
  'click #Ajouter' : function(){
    const vidURL = document.getElementById("URL").value;

    Chansons.insert({
      URL : vidURL
    });
    const URLs = Chansons.find({},{ fields: { URL: 1, _id: 0 } }).map((chanson) => chanson.URL);
    console.log(URLs);
  }
});
```

Comment: `imports/ui/body.js:17:14: Unexpected token, expected ";"` this says that the line number 17 at character place 14, needs semicolon of body.js file. Please check your code or add your body.js

Comment: Yes, I know what this means. Except that there shouldn't be a `;` here. Since line 17 character 14 is between `constructor()` and `{}`.

Comment: would be helpful if you add the body.js content here.

Comment: Just added it :)

Comment: `constructor()` is not inside any class declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement with `constructor() {}` outside of a `class` declaration is invalid syntax.

You can declare a function using the short syntax version only within the scope of an object (or a class) in ES6. They are referred to as "methods" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions)

With Meteor's Blaze frontend, you probably want to subscribe when the template instance is created, i.e.:

```
Template.body.onCreated(function () {
  this.subscribe("chansons"); // Similar to Meteor.subscribe, but scoped to the template instance.
});
```

Comment: Thanks ! Even though it doesn't get me an error, I don't see anything in the database when I use `CTRL + M` to access MongoDB.

Comment: This sounds like a different issue. Please open a new question with relevant details if you need help on that.